# rails select query creating alias for attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

With the goal of creating a JSON string, the requirement is to use an existing attribute and assign it, in the JSON output, with the attribute name `id`.

```
@valids = Destination.limit(10).select(:name, :long_name, :other_code).as_json(except: :id)
```

*`except: :id` is being invoked to avoid confusion, as `other_code` attribute is intended to be the id in the generated JSON.*

this will then be transformed into valid JSON via

```
@valids.to_json
```

how can `other_code`  be output as `id` ?

Comment: if i understand what you want. is it something like {"other_code": "id"} equivalents

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that with a simple string instead of symbols.

```
Destination
  .limit(10)
  .select('name, long_name, other_code as id')
  .as_json
```

Comment: It works while `other_code` has same type as `id`. Fortunately, it seems it has.

Comment: Alas, as fortune would have it: not. (misleading comment removed...) It is not of the same datatype and thus a `0`is being returned.  So is there no label substitution that can be done on the output, from `{\"id\":null,\"other_code\":\"IN\"}`to `{\"id\":\"IN\"}`

Answer (score -1):

Honestly am new to  Ruby on rails but very experience with json and frontend application responses

You can try this. if it work, you can now try it with your database responses. Ensure that column id exist in that your database

```
def your_definition_here

    respond_to do |format|

        @valids='999'
        format.json do
          render json: {id: @valids}.to_json
          #render json: {id: @valids.id}.to_json
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: yes, regarding rails, you're misreading the syntaxic issue.  The DB column is `other_code`, but it needs to be output in the JSON as `id`.  It most probably is a ruby command employing `as`...